# how to solve a problem wtth creating board using p5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to make a board like monopoly board in p5. I have some problem with my width and height of my canvas because it's not look like I want to.
It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA2BF.jpg

and I want something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OQg6.jpg

Here is code:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 800);
  background(255);
  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

    var posX = map(i, 0, 11, 0, width);
    var posY = map(i, 0, 11, 0, height);
    var posX2 = map(i, 0, 11, 0, width);
    var posY2 = map(i, 0, 11, height, 0);

    var tileRowUp = new Tile(posX, 0, 80, 80);
    
    tileRowUp.show();
    
    var tileColLeft = new Tile(0, posY, 80, 80);
    
    tileColLeft.show();

    
    var tileRowdown = new Tile(posX2, height - 80, 80, 80);
    
    tileRowdown.show();
    
    var tileColRight = new Tile(width - 80, posY2, 80, 80);
    
    tileColRight.show();


  }
  //var mysteriousCard1 = new Tile(170, 190, 100, 100);
  //mysteriousCard1.show();  
  //  var mysteriousCard2 = new Tile(470, 490, 100, 100);
 // mysteriousCard2.show(); 

}

class Tile {


  constructor(x, y, lar, alt, img) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.lar = lar;
    this.alt = alt;
    this.img = img;

  }

  show(){
  //noStroke();
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.lar, this.alt);

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I can't find how to solve this.Maybe somebody have some ideas?

Comment: Your width and height should be 880, 880 if you want to fix the tile size as 80x80. Or you need to find the width and height of the rectangles that you want to draw based on the width, height of the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

You're fixing the width and height of each tile as `80, 80`.
If you want it to be fixed you'll have to change the canvas width and height to be `80*11, 80*11` i.e. `880, 880`.

Whereas if you don't want to fix the canvas size and restrict it to be a square.
You need to draw each tile with a width of `width/11, height/11`.
Thus your code would become

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 800);
  background(255);
  const n = 11;

  // compute height and width
  var h = height / n;
  var w = width / n;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    var posX = map(i, 0, n, 0, width);
    var posY = map(i, 0, n, 0, height);
    var posX2 = map(i, 0, n, 0, width);
    var posY2 = map(i, 0, n, height, 0);

    var tileRowUp = new Tile(posX, 0, w, h);
    tileRowUp.show();

    var tileColLeft = new Tile(0, posY, w, h);
    tileColLeft.show();

    var tileRowdown = new Tile(posX2, height - h, w, h);
    tileRowdown.show();

    var tileColRight = new Tile(width - w, posY2, w, h);
    tileColRight.show();
  }

}
```

Now if you want squared tiles you need to have `width = height`.

You can run the above code [here](https://editor.p5js.org/phanirithvij/sketches/bRvoAN5D4) in p5.js web editor.

> Note:
>   When you're handling the game logic if you do it using the `Tile` class you need to be careful as you have a few Tile objects drawn on top of each other.

Comment: thanks for help,I was thinking and maybe you know how can I for example change the code and make 40 Tile() object and replace ```for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {}``` this loop ```for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {}``` and then I will have 40 object because now I dived this I have tileRowUp-10 Tile(), tileColLeft -10 Tile() ,tileRowdown -10 Tile(), tileColRight-10Tile() Is it possible to change this?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need 40 horizontal tiles and 11 vertical tiles, is that correct?

Comment: I need 20 horizontal and 20 vertical=40 ,sorry If I explained wrong .what I would like to have is to have  not divided like:tileColRight,tileRowUp,tileColLeft ,tileRowdown -just make like TotalTile[40]

Comment: Look at this one https://editor.p5js.org/phanirithvij/sketches/Eg_Fnzf0q. You can change n, m values to 20, 20. And width and height values can be adjusted. You can accept this as an answer if this resolved your issue.

Comment: what I would like to have is to have not divided like:tileColRight,tileRowUp,tileColLeft ,tileRowdown -just make like TotalTile[40]-have everything in one list

Comment: Create an empty list `var = tiles = [];` and push the tiles right after creating them i.e. `tiles.push(tileRowUp);` then `tiles.push(tileRowLeft);` etc..

Comment: Thanks for help but it is possible to do firstly 40 Tiles object because  when I will use push it will be bad because I am taking data from database and it will be much better if I will have on start 40 Tiles